# CoreBluetooth does not call didDisconnectPeripheral when flight mode toggles

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a `CoreBluetooth` app. This starts connection in foreground and starts sending/receiving data and continues doing this when sent to background since I have added `bluetooth-central` to `UIBackgroundModes` in `app-Info.plist`.

If I toggle the flightmode setting my app gets disconnected, but it wont get the `didDisconnectPeripheral` callback. Why is this?

My workaround has been to clear all references to my `CBPeriperal` object within `centralManagerDidUpdateState` to be able to do a new scan and connect when the app is brought to the foreground again.

Comment: If you switch off only the Bluetooth Settings (and not via Flight Mode), does your didDisconnectPeripheral get called?

Comment: @Larme, the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Same answer to your other question -> [App don't discover services when reconnecting after power cycling bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966407/app-dont-discover-services-when-reconnecting-after-power-cycling-bluetooth/18091857#18091857)

You need to call `cancelConnection:` on all your peripherals when your centralManager updates to `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff`

Comment: Still won't execute the callback `didDisconnectPeripheral`, or will I just not see it in console (my `NSLog`'s) because I am still in the background?

Comment: Have you ensured that you are properly deallocating the peripheral when you get the CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff notification?

Comment: right after I cancel connection I set my peripheral object to `nil`. Is there another way to ensure proper deallocation?

Comment: This also does not work for me. You shouldn't have to deallocate the peripheral. If you do that and `didDisconnectPeripharal` was called you wouldn't know which one disconnected.

Comment: The docs specifically say "You should issue commands to the central manager only when the state of the central manager is powered on". This includes `cancelPeripheralConnection:`

Comment: If you try to disconnect a peripheral when state is Off, you get an error from the System.