# App don't discover services when reconnecting after power cycling bluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

When I am toggling bluetooth while connected to a `CoreBluetooth` peripheral I do a disconnection and deletion of all references to my peripheral in the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` callback.

Doing another scan will find and reconnect to the device and again issue a `discoverServices`, but this time around the callback `didDiscoverServices` never happens. By deleting all settings (General -> Reset -> Reset all settings)  or do a reboot it works again. Disconnect/reconnect as normal does also work. How can I work around this or delete all cache and UUID's stored by iOS programatically?

Answer (score 1):

When you get the callback that the centralManager state has changed to `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff`, you need to loop through all your peripherals and call `cancelConnection:` on them. Then you'll be good to go.

```
[_yourCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:yourPeripheral];
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. It still don't get the `didDiscoverServices` callback

Comment: In fact, you get this is you try to cancel a peripheral connection on .poweredOff: [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBCentralManager: 0x1c447db00> can only accept this command while in the powered on state

Answer (score 0):

If the central state is `CBManagerStatePoweredOn`, and call the `cancelPeripheralConnection` API like this:

```
[self.centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:self.peripheral];
```

the callback method `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` will be called. But if the state is not `CBManagerStatePoweredOn`,  such as `CBManagerStatePoweredOff`, this callback will not execute.