# CoreBluetooth never calls didDiscoverServices on iPhone5S

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Most of the time, the app we are coding works quite well with our BLE peripheral. Often for iPhone 5S users the device gets in a funk and whenever we scan for services, the `didDiscoverServices:` delegate method is never called. Rebooting the device or deleting all settings (General -> Reset -> Reset all settings) fixes the problem temporarily.

Once the device exhibits this problem, even *other* apps (eg. LightBlue) are affected; no peripherals are able to discover services until a reboot.

For context, our BLE peripheral does not currently support pairing.

What is causing this problem? Are there any ways to avoid causing the instability? Once it happens, is there a way that the app can recover from it automatically?

Some issues with similar symptoms: [App doesn't Discover Services When Reconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966407/app-dont-discover-services-when-reconnecting-after-power-cycling-bluetooth) and [Not Scanning for Services in iPad Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919373/ios-corebluetooth-not-scanning-for-services-in-ipad-air)

Update: Just FYI, I'm still working on this problem, but *something* we did caused it to happen way less (therefore it's not really a priority ATM). I don't know what caused the added stability yet.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on iOS 7.1?

Comment: Yes, I saw it on iOS 7.1 as well, though I suspect (with no empirical data) that it happened less often.

Comment: does LightBlue stop discovering all services or just yours?

Comment: All services, AFAICT. It's like the BLE stack just stops being able to discover any services.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue which is causing real problems. Do you have anything more recent to add?

Comment: @Darren It's still inconclusive, but I've noticed scanning less and limiting the amount of data transferred helps significantly. Another thing is to only connect to one device at a time.

Comment: Thanks @ThaneBrimhall I have tested some more and it seems this is fixed in iOS 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably an iOS bug

1) Enable bluetooth logging on your device
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/bluetooth/

2) Use a packet sniffer to observe the connection between iOS and BLE peripheral